# Is it possible to return a first/firstordefault in Iqueryable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

Hi Good Day to all of you!

Is it possible to return a `FirstOrDefault` in an `IQueryable`?
See code below:

```
    public IQueryable<RequestStudents> Get(int key)
    {
      if (key < 5)
      {
        var result = context.RequestSet.Where(x => x.YearLvlId == key);
        return result;
      }
      else 
      {
        var result = context.RequestSet.First(x => x.Id == key);
        return result;
      }


    }
```

Let me know if you need further Questions.

*note that I tried to use where it returns single result in web api but in array. I want something like Single/First/orDefault.

Comment: why not `context.RequestSet.Where(x => x.Id == key).Take(1).AsQueryable()`

Comment: Is this working as expected? What is your question?

Comment: Hi @MichałTurczyn it is not working it gives error Cannot Convert implicitly. Implicit conversion does not exist (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: No, First or default will return the generic object of your current List of objects

Comment: Hi @Jorge is there a way or a workaround for that as there is only one key that is being passed

Comment: I'll suggest refactoring your method with two signatures for each case and call each one according

Answer (score 0):

`First` or `FirstOrDefault` will return object of the generic type (in your case `RequestStudents`). You have to wrap it in some `List<RequestStudents>` or other class, that implements from `IQueryable`. For example:

```
var result = context.RequestSet.First(x => x.Id == key);
return new List<RequestStudents>(){ result };
```